# Gatling global pause

Tags: gatling

I've read https://docs.gatling.io/reference/script/core/simulation/#global-pause-configuration but not sure where the `pause(duration)` element is. Can anyone give a full working example?

I've tried the following. Looking at the simulation result, there is not any pause between requests.

```java
ScenarioBuilder scenario = scenario("scenario")
    .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
    .exec(
            http("...").get("..."),
            http("...").get("..."),
            ...
    );

{
    setUp(
            scenario.injectOpen(atOnceUsers(1))
                    .constantPauses()
    ).protocols(httpProtocol);
}
```

Comment: You added the pause at the start of the scenario, not between the requests. See [this link](https://docs.gatling.io/tutorials/advanced/) which has an example showing pause between requests.

Comment: thx @GeorgeLeung I know, but I have near 100 requests, and I'm looking for a global way instead of calling pause() for 100 times.

Comment: Not possible for now then.

Comment: Not a global setting, but `flatMap` saves you the trouble of writing `.pause` 100 times.

Comment: Gatling DSL is embedded in a general purpose language. Stuff inexpressible in Gatling can be written in Java instead. We can write `List<Executable> actions = List.of(http("...").get("..."), ...);`, then `scenario("scenario").exec(anotherAction, actions.stream().flatMap(a -> Stream.of(a, pause(Duration.ofSeconds(10)))).toArray(Executable[]::new))`

Comment: @StéphaneLANDELLE
https://docs.gatling.io/reference/script/core/simulation/#global-pause-configuration
if it doesn't mean to apply to every request, then what is the meaning of "global"?

Comment: It applies a global behavior to every defined pause.